# Conditionally render a view if it exists? How to call render from a second method in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to render a custom partial if it exists, because I am running multiple websites with one codebase.  The views are generally the same but sometimes they are different enough that it's easier to render a custom view.

Does anyone know how to call render from a method like below?  The problem I am running into is that you have to call return after calling render, but I have to call return in the "index" method rather than calling the return in the "render_custom_view_if_exists" method.  I can't seem to find a clever way to automatically check if the view exists and render it, since I would have to manually go into every method to call a return to cancel rendering the default view.

```
class ApplicationController
  after_action :render_custom_view_if_exists

  def render_custom_view_if_exists 
    render "#{path}" if lookup_context.template_exists?("#{path}") 
    return true
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
end



ERROR: Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. 
Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. 
Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, 
so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".
```

Comment: It seems like it would be a lot easier to render a partial. You can have a shared index template page, and then in that view you could conditionally render different partials.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [append_view_path](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/append_view_path/class)